# How to use break and cin in array loop string in c++

Tags: arrays, string, for-loop, break, cin

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  string day[]={"Monday", "Tuesday", "wensday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
  cin>>day[];
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(day[i]==day[]){
      break;
    }
    cout<<day[i]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Still not printing

Comment: `cin>>day[];` and `if(day[i]==day[])`? How does that even compile?

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
cin>>day[];
```

with this:

```
string s;
cin >> s;
```

and this:

```
if (day[i] == day[]) {
```

with this:

```
if (day[i] == s) {
```

But.. you probably need to RT*M.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what exactly you are trying to do :(
but if you are trying to print all days  which are appearing  before a specific day which is present in string array
then below is the implementation

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
  string day[]={"Monday", "Tuesday", "wensday", "Thursday", "Friday"};
  string specific_day;
  cin>>specific_day;
  for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    if(day[i]==specific_day){
      break;
    }
    cout<<day[i]<<endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

output

```
// if specific day is wensday
Monaday
Tuesday
```